# Cell click event in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 2 `GridView` in same page, On click on `Gridview1` cell has to change data in `Gridview2`.
Is their any way doing this in c#.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowCreated">   
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView2" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowCreated"    
       PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
       onpageindexchanging="gv_PageIndexChanging" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="5" AllowSorting="true" onsorting="gv_Sorting" >
```

`Databinding` is happening in codebehind

Comment: You just need to know the row that was clicked or the cell?

Comment: Check the title of the question :P

Comment: Refer that link 
 http://interviews.dotnetthread.com/2009/02/making-gridview-rows-or-individual.html

Comment: Tim that would be fine  if i able to get cell value.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but I will try to help. have you tried anything like this in your code behind.

```
  string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
```

This would go in one of the Gridview events such as Gridview Selected index changed. Play around with the variations if this doesn't work correctly. If the cell value that you need is from one specific column this should work. change Cells[0] to Cells["Your Column Index"].